# Separate boundary from adjacent polygons

Tags: arcpy, polygon, line, spatial-join, boundaries

I have a list of polygon features that share a common boundary. Is it possible to extract that line somehow? I am thinking about making a spatial join that shows me polygons that share a line segment, but how can I extract the line that is the reason for their join.

For example, in the picture, polygons 454 and 218, 1147 and 684, 684 and 56 share a boundary (circled in blue).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest that you can use is [polygon to line](https://desktop.arcgis.com/fr/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/polygon-to-line.htm), but you need an advanced licence

```
arcpy.PolygonToLine_management (in_features, out_feature_class, "IDENTIFY_NEIGHBORS")
```

All lines with a positive left and right FID value are shared (lines that are not shared will have a LEFT_FID or a RIGHt_FID = -1).

Answer (score 2):

Make two feature layers, one for each polygon, Intersect with Line output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I you don't mind using a non-ESRI solution - then [Mapshaper](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper) (Command Line) will do exactly what want.

The `-lines` [option](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Command-Reference#-lines) will convert your polygons to topological boundaries from which you would be able to extract the internal (shared) boundaries.